# Are the BigQuery quotas per query or per row changed?

Tags: google-bigquery

I see that BQ allows us to update / delete rows. The quota limits are specified here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-manipulation-language

1)My question is whether delete statements in the quota are number of queries issued or number of rows affected. For instance if I did 
    DELETE from Table where id in (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
does that count as a single statement or 8 statements?

2) Also can I insert multiple rows into a table with one statement counting towards my quota / pricing.

Lastly, are table$20150101 and table$20150102 considered two separate tables or one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. number of DML queries - not rows affected. so in your example  - it is one statement
2. yes
3. here I am not sure  - i would expect those two partitions to be threated as a one table. But, as I said  - i am not sure

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery removed the DML quota limits, so no need to worry about the count any more.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dml-without-limits-now-in-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery DML is not currently supported on partitioned tables.  See the restrictions [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-manipulation-language)

Comment: You didn't answer the question, and the link you posted is exactly the same as the link in the OP's question...